# Как получить имя домена из GET запроса на мой сайт

Tags: php, get

Суть вопроса такова, имеется база данных, в ней таблица с полями: домен, токен. Когда с другого сайта выполняется GET запрос к моему скрипту, мне нужно проверить есть ли в базу домен и токен для этого сайта. Если имеется, отдать данные, если домена и токена нет, выдать ошибку. То есть нужно проверить, даже если токен верен, но домен неправильный, выдать ошибку. Как на примере PHP данное можно реализовать? Буду благодарен за любые советы.

Comment: GET запрос же делает не сайт на каком-то домене, а скрипт, который ничего не знает про этот домен. Подозреваю, что можно вытащить только ip сервера. Можно сравнить ip домена и ip с которого пришел запрос скрипта но будет не очень точно

Comment: $sut=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']  обрезать по регулярке и в базе  like "%'.$sut.'%" искать

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php